# Django - TypeError: load_stations() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'?

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I'm trying to create dependent dropdowns and when I tried compiling I got this error

```
File "C:\...\operations\urls.py", line 13, in <module>
    path('ajax/load-stations/', views.load_stations(), name='ajax_load_stations'),
TypeError: load_stations() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

My current code associated with this part is

**views.py**

```py
class EnterExitArea(CreateView):
    template_name = "operations/enter_exit_area.html"
    form_class = WarehouseForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('enter_exit_area')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.submit_time()
        return super().form_valid(form)


def load_stations(request):
    work_area_id = request.GET.get('work_area')
    stations = StationNumber.objects.filter(work_area_id=work_area_id).order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'operations/station_number_dropdown_list_options.html', {'stations': stations})
```

and my urls is

**urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'enter-exit-area/$', EnterExitArea.as_view(), name='enter_exit_area'),
    path('ajax/load-stations/', views.load_stations(), name='ajax_load_stations'),
]
```

What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using function based views incorrectly.

This line:
`path('ajax/load-stations/', views.load_stations(), name='ajax_load_stations'),`

should be

`path('ajax/load-stations/', views.load_stations, name='ajax_load_stations'),`

As you do not include the brackets for a function based view call.